# matplotlib xkcd and black figure background

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a plot using `matplotlib`'s `xkcd` package while having a black background. However, xkcd seems to add a sort of **white contour line around text and lines**. On a white background you can't see this white frame, but on a black background it is really annoying.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Maybe an option how to change the white contour lines to have the background color instead?

minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use(['dark_background'])
plt.xkcd()
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'black'

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.text(0, 10, "Text", color='r', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("$x$"   )
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$")
plt.show();
```

[image: minimal example of xkcd with black background]:

Edit:
I am using `Python 3.5.4` in my jupyter notebook with packages:

- `matplotlib==2.2.2`, backend='TkAgg'
- `jupyter==1.0.0`
- `notebook==5.5.0`

Note, when running the above code as a script I somehow don't get a xkcd plot at all. Only from jupyter notebook or command line I get the described behaviour.

Comment: In matplotlib 2.2.2 you need to use `plt.xkcd` inside a context, see [official example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/showcase/xkcd.html). This will solve the "run this in script"-problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you give the `plt.xkcd()` command, try executing

```
from matplotlib import patheffects
plt.rcParams['path.effects'] = [patheffects.withStroke(linewidth=0)]
```

This solved the problem for me!

Edit: I ran the code you gave with the suggested changes.

Input:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patheffects

plt.style.use(['dark_background'])
plt.xkcd()
plt.rcParams['path.effects'] = [patheffects.withStroke(linewidth=0)]

plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'black'

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.text(0, 10, "Text", color='r', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("$x$"   )
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$")
plt.show();
```

Output (Sorry, I have to link to the output image, because a newbie on Stack is not allowed to embed images in their answer):

[You might want to change your axis colors to white, though, if you want the background to be black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7SP2.png)

Comment: Note to the exact color inversion of the source code is `patheffects.withStroke(linewidth=4, foreground="k")`, which separates lines going over each other

Comment: White axes:  `ax.spines[:].set_color('white')` (need an axes object).