# Matplotlib 2.2.2 fails to xkcdify plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I use matplotlib 2.2.2 with Python 3.5.2

When I try to use matplotlib's xkcd function, I get a normal graph:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.get_cachedir())
print(matplotlib.__version__)

import matplotlib.font_manager
x = [f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist if f.name.startswith("Humor")]
print(set(x))

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.xkcd(scale=10, length=100, randomness=20)
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10)))
plt.title('Whoo Hoo!!!')
plt.show()
```

Output:

> /home/thatsme/.cache/matplotlib
>   2.2.2
>   {'Humor Sans'}

So, Humor Sans is installed, I deleted the font cache, just in case, as suggested by other threads, I increased the jitter parameters, but nonetheless no sign of xkcdification:

[image]

Strange thing is that I have Eclipse installed as a dual-boot on Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10, and the xkcd function fails on both systems. I would have expected that the Python and Eclipse installation significantly differs between those systems, but here we are.
Any ideas, what might be the problem?

Edit: As Hans pointed out this might be a problem specific for matplotlib 2.2.2
Even more bizarre - if I run the same script using `with :` without any other changes like

```
with plt.xkcd(scale=10, length=100, randomness=20):
    plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10)))
    plt.title('Whoo Hoo!!!')
plt.show()
```

the output is the expected xkcd figure:
[image]

Removing the `with :` statement brings back the first figure. The same behaviour again on both Linux and Windows, so seemingly a matplotlib version problem.

Edit: Now that we know it is a temporary, limited bug, back to the main question - [How to get rid of the white edgecolor in xkcd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50845646/8881141)

Comment: Works in WinPython3.6.3 (mpl 2.1.0).

Comment: This seems to be an issue with matplotlib 2.2.2. I just ran your script in a 2.1.2 (Python 3.5.2), and the lines were very jittery. Updated matplotlib to 2.2.2, reran, and the lines were no longer jittery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug purely present in matplotlib 2.2. The problem is that the garbage collector is too quick. See [this comment and below](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9603#issuecomment-374913081).

This means that currently you *need* to use the xkcd style inside a context to make it work. The problem [should be fixed in the next release](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10856). The code from the question hence works as expected in the [current development version](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib).

Comment: Ha. Marvellous graph in the link and thanks for speaking out to keep xkcd. I am surprised that not other scripts using rcparams seem to be affected as I understand that xkcd() works by modifying them.

Comment: [I think this only affects `xkcd`.](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10856/files#diff-43183989add1c60a82728118bd9efe98L409).